Find command slow when I'm not piping into awk
I have a script I've used for many years for building a list to some directories, with the following lines:
 ##Find all scenarios for this sector number

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name ${current}"*" -type d | \
   awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  > Sector_${current}_list.txt

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name "3T${current}*" -type d | \
   awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  >> Sector_${current}_list.txt

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name "4T${current}*" -type d | \
   awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  >> Sector_${current}_list.txt

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name "Sector_${current}*" -type d | \
   awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  >> Sector_${current}_list.txt`

This gives me a list of only the directory names. The commands take a split second to complete. Recently, we've found a need to start with full path statements in a similar script. I rewrote the section without the pipe into awk as follows:
   ##Find all scenarios for this sector number, put them into list

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name ${current}"*" -type d \
   > Sector_${current}_list.txt

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name "3T${current}*" -type d \
   >> Sector_${current}_list.txt

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name "4T${current}*" -type d \
   >> Sector_${current}_list.txt

   find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* -name "Sector_${current}*" -type d \
   >> Sector_${current}_list.txt

This gives me the same list with full path statements, and works, but it takes nearly a minute to complete. It's searching the same tree structure, with the same variable input.
Why is the second one, which seems "simpler", so much slower?

Are the pathnames that are found by find very long (and many)?  Why do you run virtually the same find command four times? Can't you combine them into a single command and just -o (OR) the name tests together?

To suggest an answer for the question, maybe there is a difference in what information from the file-system is currently cached? There are other reasons of course, maybe your output disk is failing :-( and this causes a lot of retries.

The pathnames for example, with "03" as the variable, are /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_1/03/03P01,  /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_1/03/03P02,  /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_1/03/03P03, etc., for a total of 7 scenarios for "03". There are four "AT_xxx" directories, each with a maximum of three directory levels, with the lowest being the scenario name.
The longest pathnames are around 50 characters, but there are very few that long, since they don't follow our naming conventions. They still adhere to the directory depth limit.

@icarus, these are running on the same machine, which uses AIX (5.3, unless they've updated it recently), and ksh93. The variables passed to the script are obtained from the same list, which is 40 lines, with a two-digit number on each line.

@Kusalananda, I DO like that combining suggestion, though! I'll check it out on Wednesday...

Is this behavior repeatable/reproducible?  If you run script “A” (with awk) today, and then script “P” (plain), and then “A” again, and then “P” again, do you still get the same performance?  (I’m looking at icarus’s suggestions that “maybe there is a difference in what information from the file-system is currently cached” and “maybe your … disk is failing”.)

P.S. (1) Shell variables should always be quoted, so change ${current}"*" to "${current}*".  (2) delirehberi’s narrative notwithstanding, it seems to be just about impossible that the shell has any significant role in this.

@Kusalananda, admittedly, these commands were borrowed from an older script, where they were part of a case esac test. Being a beginner to intermediate guy, I didn't know about the -o option. It's touched on in my old Nutshell book, but there's no example given.
@G-man, Yes, the behavior is consistent in both scripts, every time, without regard to what order they're run in.

Being consistent makes this problem much more interesting! You hint that this might be part of a larger script. How are you measuring the time it takes? If it is part of a larger script might the first part also traverse the file system and hence cache the data? If you replace the awk part with cat do you see the same relative performance?

@icarus, this is the first operation sequence after reading the input file in a while read statement. The input file is approximately 40 lines, 39 of which are two-digit numbers, some with leading zeroes. The first line read is "03". My "measurement" is just a QAD echo "Processing sector ${current}" immediately after this code. Not very ksh-onic, I know.
After the list is built, I clean it up a bit, and use it in a second while read loop to build hard links for XML-based command files that are used by the simulator. That loop runs very quickly in both scripts.

Pipelining with awk allows the commands to process results in a stream, reducing the overhead associated with storing and then writing the full paths.
Direct writes to the file without awk mean the shell must handle more data and perform more disk I/O operations, which can be considerably slower, especially on systems with high disk latency or many small files.
Try this:
find /gsgt/source/scenarios/AT_* \( \
    -name "${current}*" -o \
    -name "3T${current}*" -o \
    -name "4T${current}*" -o \
    -name "Sector_${current}*" \
    \) -type d > Sector_${current}_list.txt


Thanks! I'll give this a shot when I go back in a few days, and let you know.

"The shell must handle more data and perform more disk ..." is wrong. The shell opens the file and passes the open file descriptor to find. It is find wgich does all the write calls, the shell plays no part in handling any data.

This solution works well for me, but still  isn't as fast as my first code section. Most of the time spent in each iteration through the script is still spent in this first set of commands. Weird that awk would be the reason for the speed difference. I had tried awk '{print $0}', but that too, was slow.
THANKS to delireberi for the code, and Kusalananda for the initial suggestion of using the -o switch.

Well, I still don't know exactly why the script was running so slowly when I typed ./myscript.sh (it has a ksh shebang), but running it as "ksh ./myscript.sh" made all the difference. The entire script runs in about 30 seconds, as opposed to 8 minutes.

What is the very first line of your myscript.sh script, and what does which ksh say?

It's a shebang, #!/bin/ksh, and which ksh returns /bin/ksh. This is on our AIX machine, recently upgraded from 5.3 to 7. The speed issue is solved if I run ksh ./myscript.sh. Pretty weird.

Both scripts indeed invoke find 4 times, but the issue of slowness in the second script isn't due to redundancy in the number of find invocations alone.
The difference in performance between the two scripts comes from how the output is handled and the perceived impact of directory traversal.
@delirehberi wrote a 1-liner that does a good job!

Both the first and second scripts run 4 finds sequentially. The first script runs awk 4 times as well.  Assuming a reasonably normal C library, both the redirected output and the piped output from find  will be buffered.

You're right, thanks! I have updated the answer with the only difference in the script that seems to slowing it down.

Your post, while not wrong, has devolved into a restatement of the question: «the first script does more stuff and the second script takes more time».  What is the explanation?  What is the answer?  What does “the perceived impact of directory traversal” mean?
